# scipy.optimze curve_fit() gives a high standard error even though fit seems good

Tags: python, physics, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

So I am trying to fit linear functions to magnetic hysteresis curves. First I am using the ruptures library to find the change points to determine the linear regions. Then I am using `curve_fit()` to fit a linear equation to this area.

```py
#Ausgleichsgeraden berrechnen
def fit(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b

#Messung 1
popt_x11, pcov_x11  = curve_fit(fit, Magnet_x11, Kerr_x11)
popt_x21, pcov_x21  = curve_fit(fit, Magnet_x21, Kerr_x21)
popt_y11, pcov_y11  = curve_fit(fit, Magnet_y11, Kerr_y11)
popt_y21, pcov_y21  = curve_fit(fit, Magnet_y21, Kerr_y21)
```

`Magnet_x..` and `Kerr_x..` being the linear areas of the curve.
But the resulting standard errors from `np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))` are at least a factor 10 higher than the measured values which does not seem to fit since the plotted linear curves seem to fit the data pretty well. And now I don't know how to fix this.

Would anyone have an idea where the high deviation comes from?

This is an example curve where I tried to fit the linear areas:

[image: example]

And this is the ruptures plot i used to determine the ranges for each linear area:

[image: ruptures]

For example for the shown curve I got errors of `Messung 2: HC_rechts = 4693.0262 +- 36583.3256` and
`Messung 2: HC_links = -3364.4523 +- 40484.9339`. And I think that's too high for the quality of the fit.

I tried changing the ranges where I am fitting the curve and I also tried to find an error using `scipy.optimize` but to no success.

I read that high standard deviations come from unused parameters in the `curve_fit` but that shouldn't be the case here.

[This](https://pastebin.com/WHmEMVMK) is example data I am plotting and trying to fit. On the X-axis I plot the first column, where I don't have any uncertainty. On the Y-axis I plot the third column divided by two times the second column.

Comment: Could you post your dataset as a link or copy pastable array? Also do you have uncertainty estimation on dependent variable?

Comment: Does the error improve or worsen if you perform the fit on a random sample of your data?

Comment: Why are there different slopes on the saturation branches? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

#### About covariance

Covariance is estimated using the inverse of the Hessian of the error between data and model at the solution returned by the gradient descent.

When covariance is high, it means the Hessian is low at the solution. Hence the curvature of the error function is low (flat region) and gradient descent is slow.

Having uncertainties several order of magnitude higher that parameters is possible when:

1. Solution found is not optimal but you landed in a flat region of the error landscape;
2. Errors on measurement are very high and model is buried in noise.

#### About your values

I could not reproduce your parameters and uncertainties with the dataset you provided. Without the exact code you used, it's impossible to tell why.

But you can convince yourself that at least parameters you have found are not possible as a slope of magnitude `4e3` could not span data in range `1e-4` with your data.

#### MCVE

I leave here a MCVE showing how to regress your parameters:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def model(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
```

Load data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Hysteresis.txt", sep="\t", header=None, names=["x", "y", "z"])
data["u"] = data["z"] / (2. * data["y"])
```

Tag data:

```
data["t"] = 0
data.loc[488:530, "t"] = 1
data.loc[530:1390, "t"] = 2
data.loc[1390:1430, "t"] = 3
```

Regress each tag separately:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
for i in data["t"].unique():
    
    q = data["t"] == i
    x = data.loc[q, "x"]
    y = data.loc[q, "u"]
    
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, y)
    yhat = model(x, *popt)
    score = r2_score(y, yhat)
    
    print(i, score, popt, np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))
    
    xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
    ylin = model(xlin, *popt)
    
    axe.scatter(x, y, marker=".", s=4)
    axe.plot(xlin, ylin)
    
axe.grid()
```

Results are stable (even without normalization):

```
# 0 0.844119238551804   [-4.29585719e-07 -1.27397584e-04] [6.27676896e-09 1.52481902e-06]
# 1 0.733147409548466   [ 8.58502916e-06 -3.05191197e-04] [8.18939540e-07 5.56526052e-05]
# 2 0.43378140123287146 [-1.62503164e-07  4.12090730e-04] [6.33832903e-09 1.69385354e-06]
# 3 0.6562435542810321  [1.18757579e-05   5.22226928e-04] [1.37632797e-06 4.97901997e-05]
```

[image]

As you can see slopes are about `1e-6` not `1e4`. Uncertainties on parameters are high but it is expected and acceptable wrt your dataset.